# AutoCompleteExtender in ASP.NET additional info

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

how do I pass additional information to the service method returning the collection of items?  I'll attempt to explain what I mean, I have 2 text boxes on a form, I need to fill out names, based of a specific account id in a database.  so, I need to pass an integer to the getNamesForDropDown method.  I couldn't figure out what to do, so I did the wrong thing, and used the CompletionSetCount to actually pass the information I needed:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public string[] getNamesForDropDown(string prefixText, int count) 
{
   String sql = "Select fldName From idAccountReps Where idAccount = " + count.ToString();
   //... rest of the method removed, this should be enough code to understand
   //... the evil wrongness I did. 
}
```

in my front side aspx file, i set the CompletionSetCount based off the Account id the user is currently viewing on that page.

```
<ajaxtk:AutoCompleteExtender 
    runat="server" 
    ID="AC1" 
    TargetControlID="txtAccName"
    ServiceMethod="getNamesForDropDown"
    ServicePath="AccountInfo.asmx"
    MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
    EnableCaching="true"
    CompletionSetCount='<%# Eval("idAccount") %>'
/>
```

So, that's definitely a wrong way... what would be the right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

azam has the right idea- but the signature of the autocomplete method can also have a third parameter:

public string[] yourmethod(string prefixText, int count, string **contextKey**)

you can Split up the results of the contextKey string using Azam's method- but this way you do not have to worry about sanatizing the user's input of the .Split()'s delimiter (:)

Answer (score 3):

Holy smoke, I think this is what I need, I swear I never saw this option before I started programming this.  Is this a new property to the autocompleteextender?

[Excerpt from Documentation](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx):

ContextKey - User/page specific context provided to an optional overload of the web method described by ServiceMethod/ServicePath. If the context key is used, it should have the same signature with an additional parameter named contextKey of type string:

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public string[] GetCompletionList(
    string prefixText, int count, string contextKey) { ... }

Note that you can replace "GetCompletionList" with a name of your choice, but the return type and parameter name and type must exactly match, including case.

Edit:  It doesn't matter if it is new or not, or whether i just completely overlooked it.  It works, and I'm happy.  It took me about 10 minutes from being confused to figuring out my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you like you can use a separator with the prefixText. So, you can pass "1:bcd" and on the service end you can split the two items:

```
string[] arguments = prefixText.Split(':'); 
int id = Int32.Parse(arguments[0]);
string text = arguments[1];
```

Comment: how can I control what prefix text gets sent to the method?

Comment: Ohh I see!! Yes you are right. The control instantly focus on the ServiceMethod without stopping in between. I will need to check on this later!

Answer (score 1):

Refer here
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-AJAX-AutoCompleteExtender-Pass-Additional-Parameter-to-WebMethod-using-ContextKey.aspx